# Dual Booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I tried to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.
After I finished installing Ubuntu on my second partition, it tells me that I have to restart, but then it just boots into Windows 8.1 without asking me which operating system I want to boot.
I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

OK, try installing Ubuntu normally. I am considering that Ubunty boots and then it asks to reboot. If this is what happens, open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run (must be connected to internet)

```
sudo apt-get install grub
```

If it says it is already installed, run

```
sudo apt-get intall --reinstall grub
```

and then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: But then would all my data from Windows 8.1 be erased??

Comment: Of course not, you will only reinstall and update GRUB (boot manager) and then you will have the option to boot with Windows AND Ubuntu when you start your PC.

Comment: What part of the booting of ubuntu would i be able to open terminal

Comment: Actually it could be both in the Live CD or in the full installation.